# How to bind datatable with unbound fields in crystal report with aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, crystal-reports

I'm working with crystal report in aspx page which contains unbounds fields. My problem is I want to bind a datatable which has two column and filled by a store procedured with two unbound fields in my crystal report and I have no idea to bind the unbounds fields with the datatable. I have read some tutorials but they always bind it with a dataset at a design time. I want to bind it manually by code in page_Load event. Could you please give me some help? Thanks for your helps!
Here is my page_load event and it didn't display any row in my datatable:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        string passedValue = Request["testValue"];
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("Report\\ProductReport.rpt"));
        DataService service = new DataService();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Product");
        tbl = service.storeGetAllProduct();
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(tbl);          
        this.CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = crystalReport;
        this.CrystalReportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }
```

And here is picture of my crystal report i've already dragged and dropped unbound fields:
[My crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGAYe.jpg)